# How to find UI widget for just_audio flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using just_audi plugin but cannot find the following in their docs

[image]

also pause method , resume , buffering progress ..

where could i find these UI's widget

any links or docs most welcome thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally these icons and UI components are included in Material components

The pause icon is like

```
Icon(Icons.pause) etc...
```

Here you can find a huge list of icons https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html
and also a lot of Material UI components
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/material